# FileNotFound Exception open file in Python with mode wb

Tags: python, linux

I tried to write in a file using the `open()` function with the mode `wb` this mode opens a file for writing, creates the file if it does not exist in a binary mode. 
When the following code is execute it throws a `FileNotFound exception` Any thought what it could be ?
This is the code:

```
dir = ""
idFile = "001"
with open("{0}tmp/file_{1}".format(dir, idFile), "wb") as file:
    file.write("hello")
```

This is the error i got after executed the code before.

[image]

Comment: Does the *directory* exist? Remember, you're telling it `tmp/`, not `/tmp`, so it's looking for a `tmp` directory *relative to the current working directory your code is running in*.

Comment: `open()` will create a _file_, but not a _subdirectory_.

Comment: BTW, always paste errors as text, not screenshots. Screenshots can't be indexed for search, take more bandwidth to transfer, display poorly on higher-DPI displays, can't be copied-and-pasted, don't work well with accessibility tools like screen readers and high-contrast fonts, etc.